# IBOutlets in a loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, items

I'm trying to do a validation system for my form in Swift for an iOS app. I created an extension to insert `IsRequired` properties in a `UITextField` object.

I would like to iterate all IBOutlets in my view and see which satisfies the condition as in the example:

```
    txtEmail.isRequired = true;
    txtPassword.isRequired = true;
    txtName.isRequired = true;
    txtSurname.isRequired = true;


    for Item in self.view.subviews {
        if let textField = Item as? UITextField {
            if textField.isRequired! {
                if(textField.text == "")
                {
                    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 ).cgColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it does not work. I have my `UITextfields` in the stackviews.

thank you

Comment: make sure to also check that `text` is not nil, e.g `!(textField.text ?? "").isEmpty`

Comment: "... it does not work"  Is a useless statement. What does your code do?  Do you get a compiler error? If so what is the error?  Does your application crash? Does it fail to do what you want to do? How, exactly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with an `isRequired` property of `UITextField`s. Where is that defined/documented?

Comment: IsRequired is my object extension property, but is not relevant. there is no error, just does not do the loop of IBOutlet objects. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Outlet Collection` instead of the `Outlet`. In this way you going to have array of the `CustomTextField`

Example:

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [CustomTextField]!

for field in self.textFields {

}
```

Comment: Work perfectly. Thank you